# Initialize resetting password by admin Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have some problem with resetting password.
I am building application where admin Creates users. Of course he is creating users with random password which he doesn't see. But I would like to add functionality of "Send Resset Password Email to User.", i mean that admin click on that button and to the user will be send an email containing link for resetting password.
I will be gratefull for any sugestions how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reinventing the wheel and since you seem to be fairly early in the development, you should consider switching to [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle). It provides all the usual user management features, including resetting passwords.

Comment: I am using FOSUserBundle. The aplication I am writing needs to create Account by admin and later to send an email with resetting password link. By the way, I already foud way to to this.